# Proper structure with a Flutter App with JSON

Tags: android, json, flutter

I'm designing an app with a List-List-Detail view (an overview of lists, each list, details of the selected item from each list) that pulls all of its data from static JSON files.

I'm wondering what's the best structure for reading, parsing, and displaying the JSON files.  Should I design models for each view: the overview of all lists, each list, and each item and have those as separate files?  Should all of the asset loading and JSON parsing take place in those model files?  Should the each view only accept parsed data in the form of a PODO?

I've been following the instructions [here](https://flutter.rocks/2018/01/28/implementing-adaptive-master-detail-layouts/) for the overall design, but I'm stuck on the best way to work with the JSON files, since they add an async element to Widget design.

Comment: Please try something first. Your question can be interpreted as opinion based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to create the Model class to handle the JSON response,

Either you can use the same model class to list-list, but dont forget to add child list items to same model

here is the [sample example](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/background-parsing/)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that will convert a response body into a List<Photo>
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => new Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Photo {
  final int albumId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  Photo({this.albumId, this.id, this.title, this.url, this.thumbnailUrl});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Photo(
      albumId: json['albumId'] as int,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      thumbnailUrl: json['thumbnailUrl'] as String,
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: new MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(title),
      ),
      body: new FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
        future: fetchPhotos(new http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? new PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
              : new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Photo> photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: photos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new Image.network(photos[index].thumbnailUrl);
      },
    );
  }
}
```